# How to convert in a normal text a bold text from an email body of the EmailTo SFDC Feature?

Tags: email2case, string, emailtosalesforce

I am trying to process a text from an email body that can contain text styled with bold or italic style. From the standard feature, Mail To Salesforce, I find this text in the description field of the Case record.

```
I have verified that the spaces are gone in those substrings that contain a number.

In example:
```

a) If the body of the email contains a text as follows: 
 "**Case detail is 9239939 of 25/09/2015.**"

The verified text in the description field, is:
 "Case detail is 9239939 of 25/09/2015."

b) While if the body of the email contains: 
"Case detail is 5656 of the date 2/06/2016."

The text will normally appear the same in the description field, too.

What I want is to find a way to avoid this obstacle.

Thank you! E.

Comment: You want the bold or without bold text

Comment: I want to process a regular text. I have verified that this translation that Salesforce does, through the Email To Salesforce feature, does not copy the text correctly.